# cocos2dx C++ CCShatteredTiles3D is slow

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x-2.x

I am currently using cocos2dx C++ version 2.0.1 and I am trying to add a shatter effect to a sprite. When I run this code I do see the shatter effect but it slows my frame rate down tremendously.

CCActionInterval* shatteredTiles = CCShatteredTiles3D::create(20 ,false,ccg(10,10), .5f);

grid[3][3].color->runAction(shatteredTiles);

(by the way grid[3][3].color is just a ccsprite)

I go all the way from 60fps to 30 just from this code running. I wanted to do something like this on 16 different sprites all at once and that makes my code run at 3fps after that. What am I doing wrong I have been trying to fix this issue for a full day straight now. Any help would be highly appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any special reason for using deprecated version of cocos2dx ?
Current version is 2.2.3 or 3.1.
This could have been a bug in that build.
I suggest updating to 2.2.3, it should take minimum effort.
Also if you have some reason for 2.0.1, try seeing that effect in test-cpp project that came with that cocos2dx.
Doing this will prove whether its cocos2dx issue or something at your end.